# Imitate css behaviour with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, button

I want to make a button that will behave exactly the same with jQuery as it behave with css.

HTML:

```
<br>
<button class="pure-css">Test</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
this is jQuery :
<br>
<button class="pure-jQuery">Test</button>
```

CSS:

```
.pure-css {background-color:#aaa;}
.pure-css:hover{background-color:#ccc;}
.pure-css:active{background-color:#fff;}
```

jQuery:

```
/* here I want the defalt position via jQuery */
{
$(".pure-jQuery").css("background-color","#aaa");
}

/* here I want the hover style via jQuery */
{
$(".pure-jQuery").css("background-color","#ccc"); 
}

/* here I want the active style via jQuery */
{
$(".pure-jQuery").css("background-color","#fff"); 
}

/* if needed (on mouse out) so one more back to default */

{
 /*back to default if needed*/   
}
```

jsFiddle live example :

http://jsfiddle.net/CtKs8/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.pure-jQuery').css('background-color','#aaa');
  $('.pure-jQuery').mouseover(function(){  
     $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');
  });
   $('.pure-jQuery').mouseleave(function(){  
     $(this).css('background-color','#aaa');
  }); 

$('.pure-jQuery').mousedown(function(){
     $(this).css('background-color','#fff');
  });
  $('.pure-jQuery').mouseup(function(){  
     $(this).css('background-color','#aaa');
  });

 });
```

Exact 100% working tested

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
$(".pure-jQuery").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#ccc")
},function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#fff")
});
```

Working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/CtKs8/13/

Cheers

Comment: Or better say onactive :)

Comment: Same principle, but with `.focus()` instead of using `.hover()` ...Here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/focus/